# Why doesn't Linux accept() return EINTR?

Tags: linux, signals

Environment: a RedHat-like distro, 2.6.39 kernel, glibc 2.12.

I fully expect that if a signal was delivered while accept() was in progress, accept should fail, leaving errno==EINTR. However, mine doesn't do that, and I'm wondering why. Below are the sample program, and strace output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>

static void sigh(int);

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

    int s;
    struct sockaddr_in sin;

    if ((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))<0) {
        perror("socket");
        return 1;
    }
    memset(&sin, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr*)&sin, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in))) {
        perror("bind"); 
        return 1;
    }
    if (listen(s, 5)) {
        perror("listen");
    }

    signal(SIGQUIT, sigh);

    while (1) {
        socklen_t sl = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
        int rc = accept(s, (struct sockaddr*)&sin, &sl);
        if (rc<0) {
            if (errno == EINTR) {
                printf("accept restarted\n");
                continue;
            }
            perror("accept");
            return 1;
        }
        printf("accepted fd %d\n", rc);
        close(rc);
    }

}

void sigh(int s) {

    signal(s, sigh);

    unsigned char p[100];
    int i = 0;
    while (s) {
        p[i++] = '0'+(s%10);
        s/=10;
    }
    write(1, "sig ", 4);
    for (i--; i>=0; i--) {
        write(1, &p[i], 1);
    }
    write(1, "\n", 1);

}
```

strace output:

```
execve("./accept", ["./accept"], [/* 57 vars */]) = 0
<skipped>
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 3
bind(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(0), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = 0
listen(3, 5)                            = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {0x4008c4, [QUIT], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x30b7e329a0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
accept(3, 0x7fffe3e3c500, [16])         = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted)
--- SIGQUIT (Quit) @ 0 (0) ---
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {0x4008c4, [QUIT], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x30b7e329a0}, {0x4008c4, [QUIT], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x30b7e329a0}, 8) = 0
write(1, "sig ", 4sig )                     = 4
write(1, "3", 13)                        = 1
write(1, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
rt_sigreturn(0x1)                       = 43
accept(3, ^C <unfinished ...>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just when I was about to post this, the `SA_RESTART` flag in strace output caught my attention. signal(2) man page says that `signal()` *"...calls sigaction(2) using flags that supply BSD semantics..."* starting from glibc 2.x.

The `SA_RESTART` flag *"...makes certain system calls restartable across signals..."*, which hides the process of restarting a call from the user. So, this is not specific to `accept()`, a number of other system calls are also affected, not that there is a clear list of which ones.

So, if you need to react to a signal from a thread that may be blocked on a system call, you should use `sigaction()` to set your signal handlers, and not `signal()`. Below is the modified sample program that does exactly that, for reference.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>

static void sigh(int);

static struct sigaction sa;

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

    int s;
    struct sockaddr_in sin;

    if ((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("socket");
        return 1;
    }
    memset(&sin, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr*)&sin, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in))) {
        perror("bind"); 
        return 1;
    }
    if (listen(s, 5)) {
        perror("listen");
    }

    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(struct sigaction));
    sa.sa_handler = sigh;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sigaction(SIGQUIT, &sa, 0);

    while (1) {
        socklen_t sl = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
        int rc = accept(s, (struct sockaddr*)&sin, &sl);
        if (rc<0) {
            if (errno == EINTR) {
                printf("accept restarted\n");
                continue;
            }
            perror("accept");
            return 1;
        }
        printf("accepted fd %d\n", rc);
        close(rc);
    }

}

void sigh(int s) {

    sigaction(SIGQUIT, &sa, 0);

    unsigned char p[100];
    int i = 0;
    while (s) {
        p[i++] = '0'+(s%10);
        s/=10;
    }
    write(1, "sig ", 4);
    for (i--; i>=0; i--) {
        write(1, &p[i], 1);
    }
    write(1, "\n", 1);

}
```

And strace:

```
execve("./accept", ["./accept"], [/* 57 vars */]) = 0
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 3
bind(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(0), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = 0
listen(3, 5)                            = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {0x400994, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x30b7e329a0}, NULL, 8) = 0
accept(3, 0x7fffb626be90, [16])         = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted)
--- SIGQUIT (Quit) @ 0 (0) ---
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {0x400994, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x30b7e329a0}, NULL, 8) = 0
write(1, "sig ", 4)                  = 4
write(1, "3", 13)                        = 1
write(1, "\n", 1)                       = 1
rt_sigreturn(0x1)                       = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
write(1, "accept restarted\n", 17)      = 17
accept(3,
```

Comment: Thanks Pawel. It helps.

Answer (score 1):

Within [Unix Network Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131411551) book, there is a section which says:

> We used the term "slow system call" to describe `accept`, and we use
>   this term for any system call that can block forever. That is, the
>   system call need never return. Most networking functions fall into
>   this category. For example, there is no guarantee that a server's call
>   to `accept` will ever return, if there are no clients that will connect
>   to the server. Similarly, our server's call to `read` in Figure 5.3 will
>   never return if the client never sends a line for the server to echo.
>   Other examples of slow system calls are reads and writes of pipes and
>   terminal devices. A notable exception is disk I/O, which usually
>   returns to the caller (assuming no catastrophic hardware failure).
>
> The basic rule that applies here is that when a process is blocked in
>   a slow system call and the process catches a signal and the signal
>   handler returns, the system call can return an error of `EINTR`. Some
>   kernels automatically restart some interrupted system calls. For
>   portability, when we write a program that catches signals (most
>   concurrent servers catch `SIGCHLD`), we must be prepared for slow system
>   calls to return `EINTR`. Portability problems are caused by the
>   qualifiers "can" and "some," which were used earlier, and the fact
>   that support for the POSIX `SA_RESTART` flag is optional. Even if an
>   implementation supports the `SA_RESTART` flag, not all interrupted
>   system calls may automatically be restarted. Most Berkeley-derived
>   implementations, for example, never automatically restart select, and
>   some of these implementations never restart `accept` or `recvfrom`.