# How to handle signals when process is waiting in waitpid?

Tags: c, signals

I have a parent process with a user-defined signal handler. Whenever a signal received, I set a global variable and in my main loop i am checking whether the signal is received or not before each input processing.

I spawning a process to process the user input and use waitpid to collect the child wait status. Meanwhile if the parent process received the user-defined signal, how to handle it efficiently ?

**Minimized code snip from my application**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t g_signal_number =0;

void sig_hup_handler()
{       
 g_signal_number = SIGHUP;
}

void do_process_cleanup() {

  //Execute 

}

int execute_user_input(char *str)
{

    pid_t cpid,w;
    cpid = fork();
    if (cpid == -1) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (cpid == 0) { //Child may take 10-20 second to process the string.
      execute_command(str); 
      _exit(0);
    } else {
       w = waitpid(cpid, &status, 0); 
    }
}

main()
{
  char str[1024];
  signal(SIGHUP, sig_int_handler);

  while(1) {

      if(g_signal_number)
      {
          do_process_cleanup();
          break;
      }
      get_user_input(str);
      if(!strcmp(str,"end"))
          break;
      execute_user_input(str);

  }
      exit(0;)
}
```

I tried the below code to fix this issue. Could someone suggest a better way to handle this problem ?

```
while (1) {

   int ret = waitpid(cpid, &status, WNOHANG);

   if(ret > 0)
         break;
   if(ret < 0)
         if(errno == EINTR)
             continue;
   if(g_signal_number)  // break the loop if signal recieved
       break
    sleep(1);
}
```

Also tried with SA_RESTART flag, But it didn't worked in my Linux flavor for waitpid system call.

```
   int main() {
   :
   sa.sa_handler = sig_hup;
   sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
   sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
   :
   while(1) {
        ret=waitpid(child_pid, &status, 0);
        /*
         *if waipid returns -1 and errno is set to
         *EINTR and g_signum is set,
         *break the loop.
         */
        if(ret == -1 && errno == EINTR && g_signum) {
             printf("signal is set, so break the loop\n");
             break;
        }
        printf("waitpid restart...\n");
   }
```

From the strace output i could see, After sending SIGHUP to PID 17618 also waitpid is not interrupted.

```
-bash-4.1$ strace -p 17618
Process 17618 attached
wait4(17619, 0x7ffc4a2e2c34, 0, NULL)   = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
--- SIGHUP {si_signo=SIGHUP, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=26521, si_uid=332691} ---
rt_sigreturn()                          = 61
wait4(17619,
```

***Environment: a RedHat-like distro, 2.6.39 kernel***

***Update***

If someone hit this issue in future please refer the answer for [Why doesn't Linux accept() return EINTR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23685816/why-doesnt-linux-accept-return-eintr)

Comment: Lose the `WNOHANG` and the `sleep()`.  Let the `waitpid()` block until the child dies or you get the signal.  `while (waitpid(cpid, &status, 0) > 0 || errno == EINTR) { if (g_signal_number); break; }` perhaps.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler . I edited the quesiton.modified the signal SIGINT to SIGHUP. If parent process received SIGHUP, waidpid will set errno as EINTR ?

Comment: `EINTR` means a signal (any signal) was received, not that `SIGINT` specifically was received.

Comment: `waitpid` can be restarted if you specify `SA_RESTART` when registering your signal handler.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler. No , SIGHUP is not interrupting the waipid system call.

Comment: @MathieuBorderé will try SA_RESTART and update.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler please refer the updated link in the question. SA_RESTART NOT SUPPORTED in all flavors of Linux.

Comment: From what I can see, the link mostly says "the behaviour of `signal()` may have changed", and the change is to use SA_RESTART rather than not.  If you want control over signal handling, use [`sigaction()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html). Other than that, I'm not sure how to help you. I don't want to spend the time converting your code snippets into an MCVE ([MCVE]) — you should provide something that serves the turn, explaining how to use it (what the user should type; what should be seen; what is seen). Add a comment to me if you update the question.

Comment: Sure. I will add the working version of code.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler .I added the working version of code as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way SA_RESTART handled is a bit implementation defined. My Linux flavor(RedHat-like distro, 2.6.39 kernel) doesn't obey SA_RESTART for waitpid system call.

but i am able to solve this issue by setting sigaction inside signal handler.

```
/*
 *test_signal.c
 */
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
static struct sigaction sa;
/****Set this variable when SIGHUP received****/
volatile sig_atomic_t g_signum = 0;

/****SIGHUP HANDLER****/
void sig_hup(int signum) {
    /****Set the signal number****/
    g_signum = signum;
    /****Time to intrupt the system call****/
    sigaction(SIGHUP, &sa, 0);

}
int main() {
    int status,ret;
    pid_t child_pid;
    sa.sa_handler = sig_hup;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sigaction(SIGHUP, &sa, 0);
    child_pid = fork();
    if(child_pid == 0) {
        sleep(1);//Let the parent print the msg first
        printf("pid:%d:child going to sleep in a loop\n",getpid());
        while(1) {
            sleep(10);
        }
    }
    else{
        printf("parent pid: %d child pid: %d\n",getpid(),child_pid);
        while(1) {
            ret=waitpid(child_pid, &status, 0);
            /*
             *if waitpid returns -1 and errno is set to
             *EINTR and g_signum is set,
             *break the loop.
             */
            if(ret == -1 && errno == EINTR && g_signum) {
                 printf("signal is set, so break the loop\n");
                 break;
            }
            printf("waitpid restart...\n");
       }
    }
return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
-bash-4.1$ ./test_signal
parent pid: 11122 child pid: 11123
pid:11123:child going to sleep in a loop
signal is set, so break the loop
-bash-4.1$
```

Send the SIGHUP to parent:

```
-bash-4.1$ kill -s SIGHUP 11122
```

Strace Output:

```
-bash-4.1$ strace -p 11122
Process 11122 attached
wait4(11123, 0x7ffca4b72c24, 0, NULL)   = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
--- SIGHUP {si_signo=SIGHUP, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=26521, si_uid=332691} ---
rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, {0x400714, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x33c6432660}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigreturn()                          = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
write(1, "signal is set, so break the loop"..., 33) = 33
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
-bash-4.1$
```