# Parent process in server stuck in accept call. How do I terminate the parent cleanly from child

Tags: c, sockets, fork

Hello from a beginner C programmer.

I have a simple server client setup. I only want one client to connect to the server, but I want other clients to be able to try and get a message that the server is occupied.

I am able to connect to the server with one client, and let other clients trying to connect know there is no room. My problem occurs when the client tells the server to shut down. The child process is able to break out of the loops and terminate. The parent, however, is not able to receive the message from the child using pipe, because it is stuck on `accept`.

I could use `kill(2)` to end the parent, but will I get a clean termination with closing of sockets and files then?

I have also tried to let the parent not stop at accept using `fcntl(sock_desc, F_SETFL, fcntl(sock_desc, F_GETFL, 0) | O_NONBLOCK);` but this opens up new problems.

I want to somehow make the child tell the parent to skip the `accept` line and continue so that it gets the pipe message and exits the loop.

If this is a bad way to terminate servers I would appreciate to learn about that.

Simplified server code:

```
void termination_handler (int signum)
{
    if(signum == SIGTERM){
        //Is this where the accept call is changed?
    }
}


void main(){
struct sigaction sa = {0}; //2b) Initialise the struct sigaction variable to all 0s beforehand.   
sa.handler = termination_handler; //2a) Set the member for handler (to the signal-handler function)

sigaction(SIGTERM, &sa, NULL);    

pid_t pid; 
int loop = 1;
while(loop){
    int sock = accept(net_sock, NULL, NULL); //After connection 
                                             //parent is stuck here

    if(kill(pid,0) == -1){
        pid = fork();
    }
    else{
         //Tell second client there is no room and close socket
    }

    //Child
    if(pid == 0){
        while(loop){ 
            //Read signal in from client to end child loop and terminate child
            //Write with pipe to parent to end parent loop and terminate parent
            kill(getppid(), SIGTERM) // Is this how I do it?
        }
    }
    //Parent
    else{ 
        close(sock);
        //Read with pipe from child to end loop   
        //After first connection, the parent won't get this message
    }
}
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23685817/694576

Comment: I've added code for the `sigaction` case to my answer. Not that your code in the question is undefined because your calling `kill` with an initialized local  `pid_t  pid;`. Anyway, if you have further questions, you should probably make them separate instead of amending this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OS will close filedescriptors for you. Unless you have other cleanup work to do (such as writing into files or removing some files), a kill with an unhandled terminating signal (e.g., `SIGTERM` or `SIGINT`) should be sufficient.

If you do have other cleanup work to do, have the child signal the parent with a signal for which the parent has a signal handler established (you need to establish the handler with `sigaction`). That will break `accept` with return code `-1` and `errno == EINTR`, allowing you to do whatever you need to do.

```
volatile sig_atomic_t usr1 = 0;
void usr1_handler(int Sig) { usr1 = 1; }
//...
int main() {  //...
   sigaction(SIGUSR1, &(struct sigaction){.sa_handler=usr1_handler},0);
   //...
   usr1 = 0;
   sock =  accept( /*... */ );
   if ( -1 == sock && EINTR == errno && usr1 ) //was interrupted by USR1
      /* cleanup and exit */;
```

Comment: Thank you! You have both suggested sigaction. Like I told the other guy, I am not comfortable to use signals right away. I will use some time to look at it, but if it is as you say, that kill will do the trick, I'm sticking with that for now. Thank you :)

Comment: ooh, this is helpful! Thank you! I added your code like in your example. Have I understood it correctly that to make it all work, I call `kill(getppid(), SIGTERM)` inside the child process? This will call on usr1_handler and execute usr = 1. So if I for instance say void `usr1_handler(int Sig) { usr1 = 1;  printf("inside usr1_handler\n"); }` I should see that output when I call   `kill()` inside the child? Doing this makes `accept()` return -1 so that the parent can move on? I don't get the output you see.

Comment: @tore Yes on kill and printfs and EINTR, although technically you shouldn't be calling printf inside sig handlers because the function's not async-signal safe (printf takes a lock to be thread-safe and if the handler gets invoked while another printf was taking the lock, you might get data corruption or a deadlock).  `man 7 signal` should give you more info on async-signal safety and `EINTR`.

Answer (score 1):

Let the child signal it's parent before ending. If done correctly `accept()` returns on signal reception, returning `-1` and setting `errno` to `EINTR`.

From [`accept()`'s documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/accept.html):

> ***RETURN VALUE***
>
> Upon successful completion, *accept()* shall return the non-negative file descriptor of the accepted socket. Otherwise, -1 shall be returned, errno shall be set to indicate the error, [...]
>
> [...]
>
> ***ERRORS***
>
> The accept() function shall fail if:
>
> [...]
>
> [EINTR]
>          The accept() function was interrupted by a signal that was caught before a valid connection arrived.

Comment: thank you! I must admit I am not comfortable using signals, so it will take some trial and error to get this right. It seems like I have to create a struct and pass lots of arguments, and if what the other guys says is true, that kill will terminate in a proper manner, I am happy with that for now. Thanks again for your time :)

Comment: Just 2 things: 1. Use `sigaction()` (do not use `signal()`). 2. Set the member for handler (to the signal-handler function). Initialise the `struct sigaction` variable to all `0`s beforehand.

Comment: hello again! I think I need some handholding dealing with this. I edited my OP. Did I add your functionality correctly? I feel like I'm way over my head on this one.